# Share files via bluetooth

Tags: hardware, file-sharing, bluetooth

I'd like to transfer files located on the harddrive of my laptop `Acer Travelmate 4002 WLMi` to my smartphone via bluetooth.

My system is `Ubuntu 12.04`.

I tried so far.

```
$ sudo service bluetooth start
bluetooth start/running, process 3315

$ sudo hcitool inq
Inquiring ...
Inquiry failed.: No such device

$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

When I press the switch on the picture it won't turn on (yellow color). It's still turned off. In `Windows` OS it was possible to turn it on.
[image]

Here, I have stuck. Do you know how to succeed in transferring files?

Answer (score 4):

Install [blueman](http://linuxers.org/howto/how-receive-files-bluetooth-using-blueman), it is an applet that will display an icon in your tray. Its context menu has a *send files* item and a *add new device* item, and a fairly straightforward settings window so you should be able to get it work out of the box.

---

In order for a user to add and manage Bluetooth devices using Blueman, the user must be added to the 'lp' group. It may be 'lpadmin' on Ubuntu/Debian.

---

Read `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf` for information about blueman user groups

Comment: +1 I use blueman for pairing too, but it sends files as text message which I don't like it

Comment: I installed blueman and started blueman-manager. The command *add new device* is disabled (gray), I can't press it.

Comment: Yes, the user is in `lpadmin` group.

Comment: @xralf I just added one more section to the answer. Does it help you to see what user group might be probably missing?

Comment: The file looks as [this](http://pastebin.com/TpZyyCXJ). When I edit it and change the word `lp` to `lpadmin` it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start bluetooth by:

`service bluetooth start` or `start bluetooth`, Otherwise hcitool would fail to contact the daemon.

To transfer files, use `obexftp` to do it (remember to pair before that)

Comment: I edited the question with your advice.

Comment: @xralf launch those command as root

Comment: OK, updated....

Comment: @xralf what about rfswitch, did you turn it off?

Comment: I edited it again. Do you think the switch on the picture?

Comment: @xralf show the output of `rfkill`

Comment: @xraf you turned off the hardware switch, `Hard blocked: yes`

Comment: It's switch for Wifi, not bluetooth. I can turn it on with the button next to the blutooth-button on the picture.

Comment: @xralf yeah, I was wrong about it, I didn't see WLAN in the output...